# add javax.* packages to android app

Tags: java, android

I'm searchimg a way to add `javax.*` packages to my android app.
The normal way to add jars doesn't work because of a dalvik error (some `javax.*` packages are implemented but not the ones I need. and I can't override core classes)
I've already found this solution on: 
[google Code wiki Link](http://code.google.com/p/dalvik/wiki/JavaxPackages%20but%20since%20API10%20android_rules.xml) but since API10 android_rules.xml is not present anymore. so I can't use the tutorial.

I hope someone can help me solving this issue, preferable on Eclipse

Comment: Which packages do you want to add?

Comment: The last time I had the same problem with overriding core classes I found no solution whatsoever. I don't want to sound pessimistic, but I think you should look for another way of solving the problem you have.

Comment: I need to add javax.xml.crypto.* to generate a  xml signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The odds of you getting `java.xml.crypto` to work are not great. However, what you can try doing is grabbing those classes from OpenJDK (since they do not appear to exist in Apache Harmony), then refactor them into a new package (e.g., `jay.xml.crypto`). Bear in mind that you will need to license your app under the GPL if you use OpenJDK code.

Comment: Thank you, I now used the xmlsec package from [Apache Santuario](http://santuario.apache.org/) because this is under the Apache license and not under the GPL